# How to search normal words on google

Tags: c#, visual-studio, google-search

How do i perform a random word Google search? I know how to use basic URL like this but I need to know how to go on Google and search Dog's and it should come up with stuff, is that possible or not?

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace SimplicityWebBrowser
{
    public partial class Simplicity : Form
    {
        public Simplicity()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// When click button navigate's to specific URL
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowser.Navigate(SearchBar.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try doing a search in your own browser and looking at the URL it sends to Google (in the location bar)? Search anything in your browser's search feature; when you get to Google listing the results, look at the location bar and see what's there.

Comment: Nope nothing on mine.

Comment: I didnt perticuly get your comment on what to do.

Comment: I'm not sure how to be more  clear. Go go [Google](http://google.com) in your web browser (Firefox/Internet Explorer/Chrome/Safari/whatever). Type `dogs` into the search area and then click the search button. Look at the location bar (the place you type `http://google.com` to go to Google) and see what's there. You need to do the same thing in your code when you execute `WebBrowser.Navigate` in the part where you now have `SearchBar.Text`. (It will be something similar to `https://www.google.com/search?q=dogs`

Comment: But that make's it a specific word not a random word doesnt it? Example?

Comment: So generate a random word, and put it in place of `dogs` in my example. Where do you expect to get the *random word* you want to search for? Do you have a place on Google you can go and click a button that says *Search for a random word*? And what exactly do you mean by *and come up with stuff* in your question. What *stuff* specifically are you wanting to *come up with*?

Comment: I dont think you get me if a random person downloaded the web browser and want's to search up for hotel's it come's up with a list of hotel website's.

Comment: Look its been 45 minute's and i dont have a clue all im a trying to do is make it someone could google something.

Comment: *Look its been 45 minutes* - This isn't *insta-help*. If your question were more clear as to what you're trying to do, it would be answered by now. How *someone can Google something* is not *search for random words*. If you want help, [edit] your question to clearly explain what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100175/how-to-search-normal-words-on-google/28100808#comment44576895_28100175) to the question, your actual question is *How do I search on a user-supplied word?*

You need to pass the proper URL to your search engine (in this case you mention Google in the comments):

```
WebBrowser.Navigate("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + SearchBar.Text);
```

If you want to support multiple words, you'll need to replace any spaces with `+` before adding it to the URL, so that if the user types `big dogs` into the textbox you add `big+dogs` to the search URL. (How to replace the spaces would be a separate question that I'm certain has been asked here before.)